# Juniper VPN compatibility with other VPNs?

Tags: vpn, juniper

This is a pretty n00b question.

I am integrating a system with a TelCo. The TelCo's policy requires that all communication must be done over VPN using Juniper's SSG-5 firewall. My current host does not allow me to host additional hardware.

Is it possible to have a software based VPN which would be compatible with Juniper's VPN or do they have their own proprietary protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Juniper Netscreen SSG-5s use standard IPSec. As long as you have an IPSec VPN software client you should be able to connect to the SSG. Keep in mind however that software IPSec VPN clients are sometimes flaky if they are free or you have to buy one to pay for the stability.

You may run into could compatibility problems depending on the software client and how the SSG is configured. Trying to troubleshoot this from the software client side can usually be difficult depending on the level of verbosity in the debug output of your client as opposed to an SSG firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into some pretty massive problems with connecting Juniper's VPN to standard software clients.  You can experience severe vpn flap as the endpoint tries juniper custom extensions and it resets the tunnel state.

Best solution is to use a SSG5 at either end, and run a LAN-to-LAN vpn using pure juniper.

Summary:
You could do it, it might work, but you might notice some significant problems if you don't have a Juniper endpoint